Accessing a live object from another microservice (Java)
I am trying to access an already created object in a microservice from another microservice.
The complete description of the problem is as follows -
framework - spring
Microservice A :
An object of TypeABC is created (Using singleton design pattern) using Create() method. I get the same object whenever I call getInstanceOfABC().
What I want to achieve in Microservice B :
When I call getInstanceOfABC(), I want the same instance of TypeABC which was earlier created in Microservice A.
Here's what I tried so far

Tried using application context to load the bean. But Everytime I do it, the spring creates new set of beans and does not return a existing bean.
Used singleton design pattern, it works well in the same microservice but fails while trying from another microservice.

But these methods doesn't seem to work. Please suggest a way to achieve this.
Thanks

Assuming a normal definition of 'microservice' (or even just 'service'), a defining characteristic is that each service runs in its own process space. Thus, absent of remote method invocation or other distributed object technology, you can't share objects across service boundaries.
While you may, shortly, consider using distributed objects, do seriously consider Martin Fowler's First Law of Distributed Objects:

Don't distribute your objects!

People tried to do that in the nineties and early noughties, and reached the conclusion that this invariably led to poor performance and hard-to-troubleshoot bugs. This experience was, subsequently, a major motivation behind the service-oriented tenet that services share schema and contract, but not class.
You don't write why you'd like to access the same (Singleton) object across process space, but the most common motivation is state management.
In general, the Singleton pattern is a poor architectural choice when it comes to state management, because it's essentially just a glorified global variable. And not only does the single-object property fail to hold across code bases (i.e. between microservice A and microservice B), it also falls apart if you deploy two or more instances of the same code base; in other words, if you deploy microservice A to two (load-balanced) servers, you'll also have two objects, despite the Singleton design pattern.
The most common solution to state management is to employ a persistent storage technology such as a database.
